# How to make Ubuntu to not suspend when laptop lid is closed

Tags: suspend, 22.04, hibernate, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-tweaks

I am using **ubuntu 22.04** on my **dell laptop** with processor **intel core i3 4gb and 1tb storage.**

I want to make my laptop to not suspend when I close laptop lid. I don't know how to do it.

I have used some methods but failed.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of search, I have found two methods to do it.

***Method 1: Using GNOME Tweaks***
First we have to install gnome-tweaks-tool.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

Then open the gnome-tweaks and follow below steps:

- Go to the General tab in the sidebar
- And **toggle off** the **'Suspend when    laptop lid is closed’** button
  [image: change lid close behaviour in ubuntu]

**Method 2: Change login configuration (for advanced users)**

If you look into the content of the file **/etc/systemd/logind.conf**, you’ll see three different types of default settings for the laptop lid closing.

- **HandleLidSwitch**: When the laptop is on battery power
- **HandleLidSwitchExternalPower**: When the laptop is plugged into a power
  outlet
- **HandleLidSwitchDocked**: When the laptop is connected to a docking
  station

[image: Default lid close settings]

If you want, you can change the value of those parameters to one of these as per your preference:

- **lock**: lock when lid is closed
- **ignore**: do nothing
- **poweroff**: shutdown
- **hibernate**: hibernate when lid is closed

I would suggest going with **ignore**

Then **save** the file do a **restart**.

Comment: This configuration is problematic. If you unplug the dock and plug the dock back in you're unable to connect to the dock, because the laptop is in a "suspended" state. You have to open and close the lid real quick to get the dock to work. This makes using a dock very inconvenient. I have found no good solution yet. On Ubuntu 22.